# DateTime does not contain a defintion for the method and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type DateTime could be found

Tags: c#, api, .net-6.0

Asp.net 6 c#, iam using extension methodthat calculate age and then called the method to calculate DateOfBirth property, but it won't recognized the calling method and give me the error below,

Note: that when using "this" keyword in the static method (this.DateTime bornDate) give me also an error , but i removed it by my friend recommendation.

[My error message and my static method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyJz6.jpg)

Comment: "Note: that when using "this" keyword in the static method (this.DateTime bornDate) give me also an error , but i removed it by my friend recommendation" - well the syntax was wrong, that's all. It should be `public static int CalculateAge(this DateTime bornDate)`. No dot between `this` and `DateTime`. But you absolutely need `this` when declaring an extension method, as every bit of documentation describing extension methods will say...

Comment: Why have you removed all the code? Note that you should show the code as *text* in the post, but we absolutely shouldn't have to follow a link to see it.

Comment: You seem to be missing `using API.Extensions;` at the top of your file

Comment: no , all name spaces hide by vscode itself but they all active, it worked , my vscode keep putting the dot{.} between this keyword and DateTime , i removed it so many time  but i removed thee dot now and it worked , can you help me to put the answer  to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well the syntax was wrong, that's all. It should be public static int CalculateAge(this DateTime bornDate). No dot between this and DateTime. But you absolutely need this when declaring an extension method, as every bit of documentation describing extension methods will say... –
Jon Skeet